# How Do Email Campaign Managers Report On Bounced Emails?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Can anyone point me in the right direction to how I would handle capturing bounced email info.  I'm looking into writing an email campaign manager and would like the ability to report that data.

Comment: Do you really want to do this in code? Any decent mail/SMTP server should have logs that can be transformed into reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bounced email is slang for a [Non Delivery Report](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_delivery_report) or NDR. Most smtp servers have their own ways to handle NDRs, typically via a BADMAIL folder.

So first of all, confirm what your SMTP server software does for NDRs. Then confirm that this is working correctly. I think that if an email fails to send, the sender will get notified .. but if the sender can't be notified (ie. do not reply email, etc) I think this is how it ends up in the BADMAIL folder.

Anyway - you need to find out and confirm that the software you're using handles NDRs. Once it does, it's easy to write some code to check that folder every 'whatever' or even put a filewatcher on it, and then parse the content of each file that is added to that folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can write an app to poll your bad mail folder to identify returned email. You should wait for sometime after sending the email before checking whether it is delivered or returned.

Answer (score 0):

Bounced email can be parsed and you can use that information to mark email address invalid or whatever. What smtp server are you using to send emails?

And can you be more specific about the kind of help you're looking for? It's not very clear if you have access to these bounds emails and if so are they in the bounced queue of your smtp server or are they in your email client's (outlook etc.) inbox.