# asp.net - How to know when email sent or not sent?

Tags: asp.net, email, logging, smtp

I'm programming in **asp.net c#**. Our website sends batch emails.

I have run into a problem where I have sent a batch of emails (about 200)
and roughly half were sent and half were not.

This also happened again where I sent 17 emails and only 10 were sent.

Basically a SQL call gets the rows and then loops through each one and sends each email using **asp email** component.

The company which I use to send the emails said they never received the request from our website to send the emails which didn't get sent.

So I want a way to allow me to know if an email was not sent. I have thought about the following. Whats the best way to do this?

1. My ideal is to get access to their email logs of emails that we send and then i can loop through and update our database saying that they were received. The current company wont allow this. Does anyone know of someone who could help?
2. I could create a logging table in sql when i send emails to the external smtp company but how do i actually know that they were received?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I had done used `try` `catch` for sending the mail. If mail is send it goes the `try` block easily.
Otherwise it goes in the `catch` block.

And I have created a log table for that.
Before sending the mail put it into your log table
And after failure or success update the log table
You can easily maintain the log weather the mail is being sent or not.

[How to check MailMessage was delivered in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973725/how-to-check-mailmessage-was-delivered-in-net)

[How Do Email Campaign Managers Report On Bounced Emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801471/how-do-email-campaign-managers-report-on-bounced-emails)

[Email Delivery Message in Asp.net(how to check whether the email sended?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767767/email-delivery-message-in-asp-nethow-to-check-whether-the-email-sended)

Comment: This is not my ideal solution. Is there a outgoing smtp server which will give access to the email logs pragmatically?